# How to test in functional test if event has been dispatched

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I am testing a controller action using a functional test in Symfony. In this test I am doing something like this:

```
$client->request(
    'PUT',
    '/api/nodes/',
    $data
);
```

Afterwards I would like to test if a certain event has been dispatched. I already tried to enable the profiler previously (and set the config accordingly) and check the data in the `EventDataCollector`:

```
$client->enableProfiler();
$client->request(
    'PUT',
    '/api/nodes/' . $data[0]['id'] . '?webspace=sulu_io&language=en',
    $data[0]
);

/** @var EventDataCollector $eventDataCollector */
$eventDataCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('events');
```

This works as expected, but the problem is that the `$eventDataCollector` only contains data about the events for which some listeners have actually been executed. Fortunately there is an event listener executed in this specific case, but I would like that to work also without any event listeners attached, since I can't say for sure that this situation will continue to be like that.

So my question is if there is a way to test if a event is dispatched, which is save, even if there wasn't a event listener attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register an event listener/subscriber in your test environment only. Its sole purpose would be to enable you to inspect if the event was fired.

Comment: Tried to do that using `$client->get('event_dispatcher`)->addEventListener(...)`, but since some time I experience problems that the kernel seems to be reset for every request... Would be nice to only include this listener in this single test, I think you are suggesting to add the listener via the configuration, right?

Comment: Yes. Depending on how your test suite is organised and what you're testing. If you're testing with a kernel coming from a Symfony project, you'll need to register it at the project level (test environment). You might also create a kernel specially for testing. Useful if you're testing a bundle in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

Yagni. Functional tests should be based on the specifications, e.g. sending some data to `PUT /api/nodes/ HTTP/1.1` should result with something (ideally) valuable for API consumers. Some data manipulations, I suppose. The test should confirm the output matches expectations for specific data permutations.

Event listening is an internal implementation of your black box and is not subject of functional testing. It should be tested in isolation. Enabling profiler, you basically change the system under test, and end up testing something that only partially related to the production code.

Comment: Well, part of the specification is that an event is dispatched, so that other developers can react on it. This is especially important if developing a framework, so it is not an internal implementation of a blackbox, but something external developers will rely on.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you need to mock a consumer of the even, and assert it is invoked.